# Error in this java code segments, just checking to see if its correct

Tags: java, extends

Hey guys I just wanted a quick reinsurance that this is correctly done:

So you have to find the error in the code segments -

Find the error in each of the following code segments:

```
//Superclass
public class Vehicle{
(member declarations…..)
}
//subclass
Public class car expands Vehicle{
(Member declarations….)
}
```

so isnt the error the fact its expands and should be extends instead correct??

```
3.  //superclass
public class Vehicle{
     private double cost; 
  public Vehicle(double c){
      cost = c;
}
(Other methods……)
}
//subclass
public class Car extends Vehicle{
    private int passengers;
   public Car(int p){
    passengers = c;
}
(Other methods…..)
}
```

Im not sure what the error is in this one, I got this wrong anyone have a clue??

Comment: 1. Copy the code in your favourite IDE 2. Try to compile 3. Read the error messages.

Comment: *"Find the error in each of the following code segments:"*  Massage my feet.

Comment: This seems like an exercise taken out from a book or test, in particular because of the "3." at the beginning of the second code extract...

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 3):

There is no "expands" keyword in java. You always have to use `extends` for class inheritance.

The class `Car` in your second example defines a new constructor. New constructors in subclasses **must** forward data to the parent class constructor like this:

```
public Car(double c, int p) {
    super(c); // call the super constructor!
    passengers = p; // your normal constructor code
}
```

Comment: Your explanation of the second problem doesn't identify the actual problem.  It has nothing to do with the fact that `Car` defines a "new" constructor.  If it *didn't* define a new constructor, it would still have this problem.  The problem is that there is no parent no-arg constructor that can be *implicitly* invoked, which means that you have to call it explicitly.

Comment: I'm sorry if my answer is a bit confusing because that's exactly what I wanted to say. Feel free to edit it :)

Answer (score 0):

Either add an additional `default` constructor in `Vehicle` as :

```
  public Vehicle(){
     this.cost = 0.0;
  }
```

Or add additional param of type double in `Car` constructor and call super as advised by @main--

Also you can update `Car` constructor as:

```
public Car(int p) {
   super(0.0); 
   passengers = p; 
}
```